# Data Retrieval from known memory address: Troubleshooting

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I'm trying to pull a 1-dimensional array of doubles with a known size and address in memory. My current function (included below) returns an array of appropriate size, but composed entirely of zeros. Obviously, this is not the data array I'm looking for. Any ideas on how I may solve this problem (or at least some troubleshooting tips), would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I am using MATLAB R2015b for processing the data. In order to retrieve the data array, I'm writing a MatLab Executable (MEX) function written in C script.

Thanks,

Josh

**EDIT**:

To clarify, what I am trying to do is to pull data from an instrument; unfortunately, the only way to control and get data from this instrument is in the proprietary software that was bundled with the instrument and which happens to be an old compiled Matlab program in .exe format. Luckily, we can automate getting measurements from it through ActiveX control, but all that these controls give us is the size of the array containing the data we are interested in and the memory address that the array of doubles starts at.

So, what my problem is, given this information, how can I read of this array so that I can process this data in my Matlab program? The approach that I was using is to write a small C program using the MEX functionality in Matlab but I am having trouble passing this memory location and successfully reading from it, if there is a better way to do this without having to use a small C program I would gladly use this as well. Thanks

```
#include "mex.h"


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{
    double  *pointer;          /* pointer to real data in new array */
    mwSize index;

    double *address,*size,*point;
    int p;

    /* Check for proper number of arguments. */
    if (nrhs != 2) 
     { 
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt( "MATLAB:yprime:invalidNumInputs","Two input 
arguments required.");
    }       

    address = mxGetPr(prhs[0]); 
    size = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    p = *address;
    point = (void*) p;
    //const void* point = mxGetPr(prhs[0]); //(double *)*address;



    /* Create an m-by-n mxArray; you will copy existing data into it */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, *size, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    pointer = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    /* Copy data into the mxArray */
    for ( index = 0; index < *size; index++ ) {
        pointer[index] = point[index];
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Your function *doesn't* return "an array of appropriate size", it returns `void` i.e. nothing at all.

Comment: Where are you getting this mysterious address from? It is not clear to me from your code that is input and what is output here.

Comment: perhaps adding a `matlab` tag would find some matlab experts

Comment: This `p = *address; point = (void*) p;` makes no sense to me. Firstly, `p` is an `int` read from a pointer to `double`. Converting that to a `void*` pointer is suspicious. The `point` is a pointer to `double` so why cast it `(void*)`?

Answer (score 0):

As other people pointed out your code is not working because 'point' points to an arbitrary address. If you look closely to this code:

```
address = mxGetPr(prhs[0]); 
size = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
p = *address;
point = (void*) p;
```

You are getting the address of an array in 'address', then getting the value of the first element of that array in 'p' and then making that value in 'p' the address of an array in 'point' which you use to read the values. To be honest, unless you are sure that the first element is really the array's address that you are looking for, I am sure that would fail to read the real values of the array.

If what I suspect is correct -mxGetPtr() gives you a pointer to the array like it does for the other array after create it- then those 4 lines of code should be written more like this two:

```
point = (double *)mxGetPtr(phrs[0]);
size = (double *)mxGetPtr(phrs[1]);
```

I say this because the returned array's address is obtained on the same way after creation.

PS. forgot to say that you need a 'return' afther emitting the error for the wrong number of arguments. :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the responses and sorry for getting back to this so late. To clarify my problem, I edited in more details regarding my specific circumstance. (See above)

Comment: Well, I can help you with C, but if you want to use matlab coding you should remove the C tag on the question and add a matlab one in order to get an answer from the matlab gurus.. ..might be you should close this one and ask directly a matlab one with the right tag.